# Angular jsonp data print

Tags: angularjs, http, jsonp

I have problem with print data in HTML. I must print data from server.

this is example of link

http://mario.com/jsapp/getdata-new.php?jsonp=2017

it's look:

```
processData([{"name":"A","open":"0"},{"name":"b","open":"1"}]);
```

my ctrl

```
myApp.controller('liveCurrencyCtrl',  function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://mario.com/jsapp/getdata-new.php?jsonp=2017")
    .then(function (response) { 
        $scope.names = response.data; 
        console.log(response.data);
    });}
```

this is my html

```
        <div class="liveCurrencyTable" ng-controller="liveCurrencyCtrl">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                    {{name}}
            </tr>
        </div>
```

Do you have any idea what I must do? When I print all JSON in HTML I have it in JSON form, but I must print element by element. Tnx for help

Comment: when I change a method to $http.jsonp("http://mario.com/jsapp/getdata-new.php?jsonp=2017") , I have error: Uncaught ReferenceError: processData is not defined

Comment: what does `console.log(response.data);` log?, put that in qstn too.

Comment: It's resposne json in same forma like on the link, I want print element by element:

Answer (score 0):

It should be x

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{x.name}}
</tr>
```

Comment: I know, it does not work, so I just wrote this wrong here

Comment: It should be `{{x.name}}`!

Comment: It doesn't work like that